# Is there a way to get all commits starting from a specific commit using GitHub api?

Tags: github-api

I would like to get a list of all commits on a specific repository, from a specific commit. Is there a way to do that?

(I'm talking about commits on the same branch)

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to do that using this endpoint:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository

Notice the `sha` parameter which you can use to start listing commits from a specific commit.

For example:

https://api.github.com/repos/atom/atom/commits?sha=9f8f03b10f3d42bab36b585473d766268ea8859d

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that api takes from a certain commit back. I was asking from a certain commit forward.